# How to deal with whitespaces in nmake Files

Tags: windows, makefile, nmake

I want to build an application (for Creo parametric, using protoolkit API) in Windows. The API includes a pre-made nmake file which the user can modify accordingly. The problem is I do not have writing permissions in the API installation folder, where building is done by default. I therefore had to copy the makefile to a different location and change the source directory variable `PROTOOL_SRC` defined therein from `PROTOOL_SRC = ../..` to `PROTOOL_SRC = C:/Program Files/PTC/Creo 6.0.2.0/Common Files/protoolkit`. The problem is that `$(PROTOOL_SRC)` is used in various other directory names and it appears there is no way to get the whole thing to compile with the whitespaces in the path (-> fatal error U1073). While "" seems to work for each individual case, it fails when referenced later via `$()`. ` and ^ do not work either. Is there a decent way to deal with this problem? Or does one have to copy the entire source folder because nmake can't handle spaces?

Comment: Without access to the actual code, this is way too vague. But no, there is generally no sane way to use `make` generally (and thus also `nmake`) with dependencies whose names contain whitespace. Something about your setup seems flawed, though. Is there any reason you can't copy the entire project to a different location, and build there? If the `Makefile` is sanely constructed you can also often override things on the `make` command line without any need to edit the `Makefile`.

Comment: You could try short names (or junctions if you have permissions): https://superuser.com/questions/348079/how-can-i-find-the-short-path-of-a-windows-directory-file#348084

Comment: Well, it's actually my first time using a makefile so I'm not familiar with the advanced stuff. Thank you for your answers. Ofc I could copy the source but it would create a redundancy since everything already exists in the program installation folder. Anyways, using short names as Andreas proposed worked just fine. Do you want to post it as an answer? If not, I will create an answer with a reference to your comment.

Comment: Ofc I'd also be excited to learn what you mean by "overriding".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andreas provided an easy to do solution: Using the short names of directories - which are 8 characters long and contain no whitespaces - instead of their complete names. For example, `Program Files` becomes `PROGRA~1`. The shortnames of the subfolders in a directory can be queried via `dir /x` in the command line.